# How to ensure that Dojo modules execute in a certain order?

Tags: javascript, dojo

So I'm using the **Dojo 1.7** 'require' syntax to fire off two modules. However, the order that these modules are called is important, as one works on the results of the other.

I can't just lay them out procedurally... how do I ensure they fire in order?

```
require(['modules/createElements', 'dojo/domReady!'], 
    function(createElements) {
        createElements.go();
});

require(['modules/modifyElements', 'dojo/domReady!'], 
    function(modifyElements) {
        // This is supposed to modify the elements created
        // by the createElements module, but it usually fires
        // _before_ the elements have been created!
        modifyElements.go();
});
```

Ideally I'd like the two modules to be more-or-less independent of eachother (e.g. so that `modifyElements` can act on elements created by any source), so calling `modifyElements` at the end of `createElements` is not desirable.

Comment: Discovered an answer that works for me, but if anyone else has alternatives or better suggestions, please leave them here! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I realized moments after posting this that I can just do all my work from within a single `require`, like so:

```
require(['modules/createElements', 'modules/modifyElements', 'dojo/domReady!'],
    function(createElements, modifyElements) {
        createElements.go();
        modifyElements.go();
});
```

Comment: Indeed. This does not guarantee they will be loaded in the order you specify, at least if you put the loader in async mode, but the callback function will only execute once all the modules are loaded.